# Javascript RegExpresion

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

here is my string

```
str = "asd;images30/127ef-30-30-wm.jpg;59 | asd;images30/127ef-30-30-wm.jpg;60 | "
```

and regexp is

```
var re = new RegExp(".*?;.*?;"+$(this).parent().attr("id")+" | ","ig");
```

and replace function is

```
str.replace(re,'');
```

i actually want to remove `asd;images30/127ef-30-30-wm.jpg;59 |` from string.
Above Regular expression return

```
 | asd;images30/127ef-30-30-wm.jpg;60 |
```

whereas expected is

```
asd;images30/127ef-30-30-wm.jpg;60 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace the `|` in your RegExp call with `\\|`. This is necessary because the single backslash will be ignored (if the character afterward had been used within escape sequences, e.g., if it were an `n`, these two would become a newline escape sequence, but for characters not part of escape sequences, a single backslash is ignored), and the additional one will cause the single one to appear. Then it can be used in the regular expression to indicate you are escaping a literal pipe symbol and not the built-in regex "alternate" symbol.

Note that if your `id` from jQuery could be non-numeric, you might also need to escape this value. You can escape it with a function like [this](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote:491).

To hard-code an ID here (based on your example, the value was apparently 59), if you remove the double backslashes, it won't remove the first pipe:

```
str = "asd;images30/127ef-30-30-wm.jpg;59 | asd;images30/127ef-30-30-wm.jpg;60 | ";
var re = new RegExp(".*?;.*?;"+59+" \\| ","ig");
str = str.replace(re,'');

alert(str)
```

Comment: i am doubtful about space before and after pipline |